# How to annotate complete images?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, annotation

I am currently playing around with tensorflows object detection to learn the basics.

Now I've set myself the goal to detect letters in computer written text. For example the header of a newspaper article.

I know that object detection might not be the way to go for letter detection but I wanted to know how well a object detection model performes when input data is perfectly similar( computer generated fonts).

**My Question:**

I encountered the problem that manually annotating each letter in given headers is a really fiddly job and feels not good for training a model.

Now I ask myself this:
I could write an Adobe script to generate me an image for every letter of a font(or multiple fonts) with different backgrounds and rotation and save it to my filesystem.
-> this would result in (10 Fonts * 256 characters * 10 backgrounds * angles) 256000 images for model training.

For training purposes this is a great amount of data but if I want to annotate each image myself it will get nifty especially because each 1000 images have the same tag..

**Question 1:**

> Is there a package or tool which annotates the complete image with a given tag?

**Question 2:**

> Will training a object detection model with "cropped images" even work or is a rational approach?

Every help/suggestion is highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you need a tool? If you can generate the images knowing the letter, you can just store the letter as label. Mind that the data you would use in this case is not a representative sample, characters (and words) do not have a uniform distribution in real text.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a package or tool which annotates the complete image with a
> given tag?

For your use case you don't need to detect each letter. you can try to detect header and annotate the bbox using tools like [labelimg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) and [doccano](https://github.com/doccano/doccano)

The bbox for each tagged image will be saved in the format you want and utilised by model.